# Algorithms for bucketizing integers into buckets with zero sums

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Suppose we have an array of integers (both negative and positive) `A[1 ... n]` such that all the elements sum to zero. Now, whenever I have a bunch of integers that sum to zero, I will call them a **group** and I want to split `A` in as many **disjoint groups** as possible. Can you suggest any paper discussing this very same problem?

Comment: Even finding if there is ANY subset that sums to 0 is NP-Complete (Subset-Sum Problem). I assume finding the Maximum number of such partition is Strong-NP-Hard, but cannot think of a proof ATM.

Comment: I know that. Finding a paper discussing this problem would be like Christmas again.

Comment: This is a really interesting question (+1). I suspect you'll have more luck on Math Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem consists of two NP-Complete problems.

The first would be finding all subsets that solve the Subset Sum problem.  This problem does have an exponential time complexity (as implied by amit in the comments), but it is a very reasonable extension of the Subset Sum problem from a theoretical standpoint.  For example, if you can solve the Subset Sum problem by dynamic programming and generate the canonical 2D array as a result, this array will contain enough information to generate all possible solutions using a traceback.

The second NP-Complete problem embedded within your problem is the Integer Linear Programming problem.  Given all possible subsets solving the Subset Sum problem, N total, we want to select select 0<=n<=N, such that the value of n is maximized and no element of A is repeated.

I doubt there is a publication devoted to describing this problem because it seems to involve a straightforward application of known theory.